# TypeScript square-bracket'ed name?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading the [language server protocol (LSP) specification](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification) and I found this definition:

```
export interface WorkspaceEdit {
    /**
     * Holds changes to existing resources.
     */
    changes?: { [uri: string]: TextEdit[]; };

    /**
     * An array of `TextDocumentEdit`s to express changes to n different text documents
     * where each text document edit addresses a specific version of a text document.
     * Whether a client supports versioned document edits is expressed via
     * `WorkspaceClientCapabilities.workspaceEdit.documentChanges`.
     */
    documentChanges?: TextDocumentEdit[];
}
```

In the `changes` field, is that a typo, or what does it mean?

Can you please explain it to one who doesn't know TypeScript and he's just attempting implementing the messages in another programming language?

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ [uri: string]: TextEdit[]; };` defines a type, which is indexable by `string` and the index returns `TextEdit[]`. `uri` is just the name given to the index parameter.

Ex:

```
interface TextEdit { TextEdit : true } /// dummy    
export interface WorkspaceEdit {
    /**
     * Holds changes to existing resources.
     */
    changes?: { [uri: string]: TextEdit[]; };

}

let w: WorkspaceEdit;
let t = w.changes['test'] // t is of type TextEdit[]
let f: number[] = w.changes['test'] // error can't assign TextEdit[] to number[]

w.changes['test'] = "" // also error since we are assigning a string to the object
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20TextEdit%20%7B%20TextEdit%20%3A%20true%20%7D%20%2F%2F%2F%20dummy%20%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20WorkspaceEdit%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Holds%20changes%20to%20existing%20resources.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20changes%3F%3A%20%7B%20%5Buri%3A%20string%5D%3A%20TextEdit%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20w%3A%20WorkspaceEdit%3B%0D%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20w.changes%5B'test'%5D%20%2F%2F%20t%20is%20of%20type%20TextEdit%5B%5D%0D%0Alet%20f%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20w.changes%5B'test'%5D%20%2F%2F%20error%20can't%20assign%20TextEdit%5B%5D%20to%20number%5B%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aw.changes%5B'test'%5D%20%3D%20%22%22%20%2F%2F%20also%20error%20since%20we%20are%20assigning%20a%20string%20to%20the%20object%20%20)

Answer (score 0):

It means that changes is an object that can take any string as a key. Without this, you won't be able to do `WorkspaceEdit.changes['anything'] = [...]`. Keep in mind anyway that every object in changes must be an array of `TextEdit`.

Comment: And what's that? Is that a way to make associative arrays (i.e. arrays with index of string type)? So is it equivalent to a mapping from string to TextEdit?

Comment: In fact, an object in JS is like an associative array in PHP, but you can in typescript either define every field your object will have, or if you don't know you put this and you can put every key you want (as long as the type matches)